# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.Calendar.before(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, nullpointerexception

The user can press three buttons: One will bring up a clock to select the time, another will bring up a calendar to select the date. The third button is to be pressed last, and is meant to send out a notification.

When I press on the last button, I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.Calendar.before(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.meeldetuletuserakendus.MeeldetuletusActivity.startAlarm(MeeldetuletusActivity.java:105)
```

Something goes wrong when trying to do the method startAlarm(c).
I know for certain that everything worked perfectly when the code only had a choice to choose a time, but something broke when I coded the date picking part of the code. So the problem probably has something to do with the date.

`MeeldetuletusActivity.java`:

```
public class MeeldetuletusActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    String timeText;
    TextView textTime;
    Button nupp_vali, nupp_katkesta, nupp_kuupaev, nupp_alarm;
    Calendar c;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meeldetuletus);

        nupp_vali = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        nupp_katkesta = findViewById(R.id.nupp_katkesta);
        nupp_kuupaev = findViewById(R.id.button);
        nupp_alarm = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        nupp_alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startAlarm(c);
            }
        });

        nupp_vali.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");

            }
        });

        nupp_kuupaev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment kuupaevaValija = new KuupaevaFragment();
                kuupaevaValija.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
            }
        });

        nupp_katkesta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                katkestaAlarm();
                Toast.makeText(MeeldetuletusActivity.this, "Meeldetuletus unustatud", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });




    }


    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    }


    public void onDateSet (DatePicker view, int aasta, int kuu, int paev) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, aasta);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, kuu);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, paev);
    }



    private void startAlarm(Calendar c) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
        if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        Objects.requireNonNull(alarmManager).setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    private void katkestaAlarm() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationPublisher.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, myIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Row 105 is:

```
if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
```

`KuupaevaFragment.java`:

```
public class KuupaevaFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int aasta = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int kuu = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int paev = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(),
                aasta, kuu, paev);


    }


}
```

`TimePickerFragment.java`: (This worked perfectly before, I'm only putting this here so you can see what KuupaevaFragment.java is meant to do aswell)

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(),
                hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));


    }


}
```

`NotificationPublisher.java`:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification();
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb.build());
        Notification notification = nb.build();
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    }
}
```

`NotificationHelper.Java`:

```
class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {
    public static final String channelID = "channelID";
    public static final String channelName = "Channel Name";
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createChannel();
        }
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannel() {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    public NotificationManager getManager() {
        if (notificationManager == null) {
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return notificationManager;
    }
    public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannelNotification() {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelID)
                .setContentTitle("Meeldetuletus")
                .setContentText("Teie valitud aeg on käes")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_active_24);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reference to the Activity's field `c` in `onTimeSet` and `onDateSet`:

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
}


public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int aasta, int kuu, int paev) {
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, aasta);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, kuu);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, paev);
}
```

So instead of `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();` write `c = Calendar.getInstance();` like in the code above.

---

Or you can try to initialize `c` property in Activity:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and use it to change Calendar's properties, for example in `onTimeSet` method:

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
}
```

Comment: Could you please create another question here on Stackoverflow and describe the problem in details, thanks.